# How to safely give an object the next highest value in a model - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to assign a `position` parameter to each user created in my Django app. The position is modified at various points down the line, however when a user is created I need the position parameter to be set to the next highest value.

The model is as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, default=0, unique=True)
```

At the moment I am assigning this parameter as follows:

```
user_count = User.objects.all().count()
new_user = User()
new_user.profile.position = user_count + 1
new_user.save()
```

Clearly if two users are registered at the same time, then there is a potential for them both to get the same value of `user_count` assigned, if that occurs before the save is made. Given the uniqueness constraint this would raise an error, but I'm not sure how to resolve it safely.

How should I do this to ensure uniqueness (and deal with any unique conflicts that might arise)?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough points to comment, or I would do that.  Depending on your DB of choice, you could just have an auto increment column that is set at the time of adding your other columns.  You also could set that column to unique and use try/except on your statement to catch the error and increment your position.